# Powershell: The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered error

Tags: windows, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to load sharepoint script from *.cmd file. 
I have Sharepoint 2010 installed on Windows 7 x64 and SQL server 2008r2.
My cmd file is: 
Powershell -v 2 -NonInteractive -NoLogo -File 1.ps1

My sharepoint file 1.ps1 is:

```
$snapin="Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
if ($action -eq $null -or $action -eq '')
{<br />
# Action by default is complete uninstallation.
$action='uninstall'
$uninstall = $true
}
 else
{
$action = $action.ToLower()
    switch($action)
{
    { $_ -eq "uninstall" }           { $uninstall = $true; break }
    { $_ -eq "removesolution" }      { $removeSolution = $true; break }
    { $_ -eq "deactivatecorpus" }    { $deactivateCorpus = $true; break }
    { $_ -eq "deactivatesupport" }   { $deactivateSupport = $true; break }

    default                          { Write-Host -f Red "Error: Invalid action: $action "; Exit -1 }
}
}
Check the Sharepoint snapin availability.
if (Get-PSSnapin $snapin -ea "silentlycontinue")
{
Write-Host "PS snapin $snapin is loaded."
 }
  elseif (Get-PSSnapin $snapin -registered -ea "silentlycontinue")
 {
Write-Host "PS snapin $snapin is registered."
Add-PSSnapin $snapin
Write-Host "PS snapin $snapin is loaded."
  }
 else
  {
Write-Host -f Red "Error: PS snapin $snapin is not found."
Exit -1
 }

  $url = "http:///sites/GroupWork/"
 $site= new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url )
 $loc= [System.Int32]::Parse(1033)
 $templates= $site.GetWebTemplates($loc)
 foreach ($child in $templates){    write-host $child.Name "  " $child.Title}<br />
 $site.Dispose()
```

The script works fine from the Sharepoint 2010 management shell after launching the shell from the start menu (or from windows cmd by entering powershell -v 2):

PS C:\2> .\1.ps1 
PS snapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is loaded.
GLOBAL#0    Global template
STS#0    Team Site
STS#1    Blank Site
STS#2    Document Workspace
MPS#0    Basic Meeting Workspace
MPS#1    Blank Meeting Workspace
MPS#2    Decision Meeting Workspace
MPS#3    Social Meeting Workspace
MPS#4    Multipage Meeting Workspace
CENTRALADMIN#0    Central Admin Site
WIKI#0    Wiki Site
BLOG#0    Blog
SGS#0    Group Work Site
TENANTADMIN#0    Tenant Admin Site
{248A640A-AE86-42B7-90EC-45EC8618D6B4}#MySite2    MySite2
{95629DC2-03B1-4C92-AD70-BC1FEAA49E7D}#MySite1    MySite1
{7F01CFE4-F5E2-408B-AC87-E186D21F624C}#NewSiteTemplate    NewSiteTemplate
PS C:\2>

I have an access to the database Sharepoint_Config from current domain user and from other 2 users. All users have db_owner rights to the Sharepoint_Config database.
But i've loaded in windows from the user which is dbo in the database (dbo with windows authentication with domain\username for the current user). The dbo user has do_owner rights in the Sharepoint_Config database. 
I've tried to login under other users and launch the cmd file but without success.

My PowerShell has version 2.0: 
PS C:\2> $psversiontable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5477
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1

After launching the script from 1.cmd file i get an errors:

C:\2>Powershell -v 2 -NonInteractive -NoLogo -File 1.ps1
PS snapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is registered.
The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not regis
tered.

Could not read the XML Configuration file in the folder CONFIG\PowerShell\Regist
ration.
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\2\CONFIG\PowerShell\Registration'.
No xml configuration files loaded.
Unable to register core product cmdlets.
Could not read the Types files in the folder CONFIG\PowerShell\types.
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\2\CONFIG\PowerShell\types'.
"No Types files Found."
Could not read the Format file in the folder CONFIG\PowerShell\format.
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\2\CONFIG\PowerShell\format'.
No Format files Found.
PS snapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is loaded.
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The Web applicati
on at
    http://Pc1/sites/GroupWork/ could not be found. Verify t
hat you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing con
tent, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the
 intended application."
At C:\2\1.ps1:48 char:18
+ $site= new-Object <<<<  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url )
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvoca
   tionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power
   Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

I don't understand why the script is launched from the sharepoint management shell but doesn't work from the cmd file.

Comment: Your `$url` has a typo:`$url = "h ttp:///sites/GroupWork/"`

Comment: I can't add the post  without this trick - the site think that url is the link. You should read url as http:// (in the script url is correct)